# Laravel glide out of memory

Tags: php, laravel, image, php-glide

I'm using Glide on Laravel and I have "small" problem with it. When I load small image by `outputImage()` everything is okay. But when I try to load - for simple - 1.6MB of image Laravel put in console:

```
 Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14152 bytes) in C:\Users\displate\Documents\displate\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\Gd\Decoder.php on line 34
```

How can I simple fix it?

Bad part of my code:

```
protected function get($path,$storage,$sizes,$prefix=''){
    ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); // it's not working :<
    if($this->check_variables($sizes)){
        $server=$this->prepare_server($storage,$prefix);

        try{
            $server->getImageResponse($path);

            $server->outputImage($path, $_GET);
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->download_image($path,$storage);

            $server->getImageResponse($path);

            $server->outputImage($path, $_GET);
        }
    } 
    else{
        abort(404);
    }
}

protected function prepare_server($storage_name,$prefix=''){
    $server = \League\Glide\ServerFactory::create([
                    'source' => \Storage::disk($storage_name)->getDriver(),
                    'cache'  =>  \Storage::disk($storage_name)->getDriver(),
                    'source_path_prefix'    =>  $prefix,
                    'cache_path_prefix'     =>  $storage_name.'_cached',

                ]);

    $_GET['fit']='crop';
    $_GET['crop']='center';

    return $server;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if youre sure that your actually running out of memory for the reasons you think, and not from some infinite loop or other error, you can increase the amount of memory that PHP is able to use by doing the following.

- Locate the php.ini file used by your web server
- Edit the memory_limit parameter in the php.ini file (usually in a section called Resource Limits)
- Restart Apache.

it should look something like this afterwards:

```
memory_limit 128M
```

If you get stuck, [this](http://tutorials.hostucan.net/how-to-increase-php-memory-limit/) looks like a good resource

64Mb, which is what you have, isnt that much. Id stick it at 512M or even 1024M if you have the ram.

Comment: Memory limit help me, I'm using now 512Mb